# How can I view the questions which I have asked but deleted?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

I searched through my profile on SO but I did not find a list of my deleted questions. Is there a hidden link like the `/reputation`?

*Truth to be told: I remember that I've deleted some of my own questions because they did not receive any answers for months but I can't see them anymore on my profile. I'm after the zombie mask (winterbash).*

Comment: You can find a link to **recently deleted** questions in the [questions list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157724/adam-arold?tab=questions) on your profile

Comment: Not really sure but go to [Questions under your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/485337/adam-arold?tab=questions) and see if there is a link for recently deleted posts.

Comment: I see 17 deleted questions, if you can narrow it down I can share a link

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 options: two for all users, one for when you have the view deleted posts privilege, and if all fails you can only hope your browser history has still a link in its cache.

#### Find deleted posts in your profile

When the question or answer was posted **less than 60 days ago** you can find them in your profile:

- For questions: At the bottom of your [question page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=1) click the *deleted recent questions* link
- For answers: At the bottom of your [answer page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=1) click the *deleted recent answers* link

[image: answers deleted]

#### With the View deleted posts privilege

If you have the privilege [*Access to moderator tools*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) you can search for your own deleted posts:

> [deleted:yes stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3Ayes+stackoverflow)

this will give you a search result similar to this:

[image]

#### Ask a moderator

If none of the options above work for you and it is really important to have that link you can ask a moderator to do a search for you. Don't go asking for links to all your deleted posts but provide a couple of search terms that should return a result to the best of your knowledge. You can reach out to a moderator by raising a custom flag on one of your posts, hop into a chat room that is also visited by moderators or post a request on Meta.  Don't make this into a habit though.